# Show only dashlet of a module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am creating a custom Survey package which has questions module , answers module and a third module named survey which has to be used to relate the question_id with the answer_id that was selected by the user.[theres a reason why these three different modules were created]

Now the questions and answers have one to many relation with survey module, I dont want to show any of the subpanel,list,edit , create or popup( all those views that exists by deafult) views for survey module and want to use the chart dashlet to show the survey result.

Can anybody tell me  how can I disable all the views for survey module ?

I hope my question is clear to everyone.

Regards,
Anand Joshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go into the custom/modules/{Survey_Directory} and create a controller.php - in that controller.php file you can override the the actions like so.

```
    public function action_DetailView()
    {
        $this->view = null;
        $GLOBALS['view'] = $this->view;
    }
```

Setting the view to null will remove the layout and everything, creating a blank method will render the layout but omit the actual views.  You could throw some code in the controller to handle a redirect if you wanted to keep people out all together.

Some common actions though are:

- action_DetailView
- action_EditView
- action_Popup
- action_ListView

Hopefully that helps get you started.

Comment: thanks , It helped me for the edit, create, list and detail view but I am not able to remove the subpanel of surveys which is created under questions and answers module edit or create page (as they have one to many realtion with surveys module)

Comment: Try this for the subpanel - navigate to custom/Extension/modules/{Your_Module}/Ext/LayoutDefs/custom.php - if custom doesn't exist you can create it.  Open up custom.php and add the following line:  $layout_defs['<modulename>']['subpanel_setup']['<subpanel_to_remove>'] = array ();
?>

Comment: If that doesn't work...in the same file you can try:  <?php unset($layoutdefs['<module>']['subpanel_setup']['<subpanel_to_remove>']); - also with both options be sure to Repair/Rebuild